# Javascript working in Safari but not Chrome or Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, dom-events

I am not a programmer at all, so I am sorry in advance, but after searching the web I cannot find an answer.

I am trying to take the inventory search from [this website](http://www.erikschevrolet.com/VehicleSearchResults?search=new&make=Chevrolet&modelId=33963&minYear=2012&maxYear=2012&cs:a:i=GM_Chevrolet-Showroom_HomePage-Chevrolet-Emblem_Hero-Image-Rotator) and put it in a Facebook tab.  I grabbed the code from the website and edited out the headers and footers, which I did not want, in TextEdit. I am only trying to take the inventory search portion.

When I tested it out in Safari it seemed to work.  The inventory search came up and all of the buttons and filters worked perfectly and when I would go to a different page the headers and footers were still gone and just the inventory search was there - perfect.

However when tested in Chrome and Firefox the buttons and filters did not work at all, and you cannot go past the first page or apply filters.

So I decided to go to the site (the first page of the inventory search like the link above) and save the source code to my desktop to see if when I opened this in Chrome or Firefox if it would work, and it didn't, no buttons or filters worked, stuck on first page.  But it did work in Safari.

What does this mean?  Should I give up now?  I would include the code but it is the longest I have ever seen.  All of the testing of the code I did through TextEdit.

**edit**:
Here are the errors in Chrome:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < Chevy.html:4608
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http:‍//www.erikschevrolet.com/searchVehicles.ajax. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
> Uncaught Error: XmlRenderEngine = >Unknown error bundle.js:1
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http:‍//www.erikschevrolet.com/searchVehicles.ajax. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
> Uncaught Error: XmlRenderEngine = >Unknown error bundle.js:1
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http:‍//www.erikschevrolet.com/searchVehicles.ajax. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
> Uncaught Error: XmlRenderEngine = >Unknown error bundle.js:1

Comment: Are there any errors in Chrome and ff? If there are, please include them. Also, the page seems to be generated on a server. If so, it would be easier to do the entire thing server-side by not including the header files, etc.

Comment: Not sure your exact use case, but be careful that what you're doing here is legal.  The code from that site is owned by "Chrome Systems Corporation", and it would be illegal to steal and reuse their code without their permission.  Otherwise, good question :)

Answer (score 1):

These Chrome warnings are not relevant here. Errors given above are about cross-origin issues. Due to really evil things in which accessing remote resources from within Javascript can result, modern browsers block them unless explicitely allowed.

For example, most content from http://example.com can't be accessed by javascript under http://example.net domain. Since you downloaded most files and you are trying to run them locally, but still some of them refer to files under the http://www.erikschevrolet.com domain, it's not allowed.

AFAIK there isn't a really simple way to avoid this issue; the safest solution would make you download all the used files and manually change references to http://www.erikschevrolet.com with references to your local path. Alternatively, one can set the withCredentials value of XMLHttpRequest to true (but since you're not a programmer, you can really mess it up...) like this (example from http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/):

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'http://bar.other/resources/credentialed-content/';
function callOtherDomain(){
  if(request)
  {
   request.open('GET', url, true);
   request.withCredentials = "true";
   request.onreadystatechange = handler;
   request.send();
  }
}
```

And even this might not get the expected result as a lot of these files are probably generated dynamically on server and are subject to change.

Comment: Thank you!  I will look into changing the references myself, or I will outsource the project to someone who knows what they are doing!

Comment: If you're satisfied by my answer, could you upvote it and accept it? ;)

Comment: Use JSONP to make cross domain requests or simply do it on the server rather than in JS

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a problem in reading an xml or text files in javascript with specific load files scheme. it happens in browsers where requests of http works, here in this case you can try out something like working in javascript,

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
```

this will act on chrome safari firefox as well try this.